# Phonegap barcode scanner not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am new to phonegap. I am implementing barcode scanner for my application. 
I am following this [link](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3):-

But i got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner'" error. Also is this example only for android? If you have any other barcode scanner library for phonegap then please tell help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this for Android

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner

And for iOS you can check

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

Choose the plugin version according to your PhoneGap/Cordove version.

Regarding the error you are facing, you can check these links 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eclipse-plugin-for-phonegap/QYvyjMwiTTw
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/W2pB0jp5cqk
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/36197